# I'd like to delete a chat

Tags: discussion, chat

I'd like to delete a chat.

The chat has more then 15 rows and therefore wont be deleted automatically.

Would it be possible to request a delete?

*Edit: 
Like you probably didn't notice in my above text is that I've read the post you are referring to which mine is a duplicate of.*

**I'm wondering how I can contact a moderator or similar to delete a chat?**

Comment: What... is... Meta.SO? Sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: Probably [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45660/discussion-between-mille-and-remou)

Comment: It shouldn't be possible - people here, both on site and on chat, are not to help *you*, but to help *community*. If conversation was valid, interesting and instructive, relevant to the question, it should stay visible. It might be valuable for future readers of that question, after all.

Comment: Why would you want to delete a chat room?

Comment: Because I thought it was private. Also "the questions has already an answer" doesn't answer my question. If it's possible to request a deletion of a chat somehow, from a moderator or similar.

Comment: @Mille you can flag one of your own posts on Stack Overflow, choose "other" and explain you want that room deleted. It might be accepted but it might as well be declined, in which case your last resort is sending email to `team@stackexchange.com` pledging your case.

Comment: That said I can't see anything horribly private in that room. You can delete your own messages there if it concerns you so much.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Best answer. If I could I'd rank it up. ;-)

Comment: Cheers, and good luck!